# Changing Date Format in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datetime, datagridview

How to change the format of date in DataGridView cell in WinForm Application?
The source format of that cell is "YYYY-MM-DD" and I want to change it as "DD/MM/YYYY".
How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: you can apply the format in this way "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the default cell style.

```
this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx

Comment: Might also want to ensure that `this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].ValueType` is set to `typeof(DateTime)`. (You know, in case someone decides to drop a string in there instead)